# jQuery swap multiple elements

Tags: jquery, html, css, swap

I have three groups (td) of a div and a link, I want to place the link before the div in each of these groups (td). I tried with after() but to no success..
Is there a easy method to do this?

I have this structure:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <div>Text</div>
            <a href="#">Link</a>
        </td>
        <td>
            <div>Text</div>
            <a href="#">Link</a>
        </td>
        <td>
            <div>Text</div>
            <a href="#">Link</a>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: What was the code you wrote using `.after()`? And what was wrong with it?

Comment: Thank you for the comment, I got it working with Josh's code..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want the `a` element to be the first child, use the following:

[**Example Here**](http://jsfiddle.net/9fEws/)

```
$('table td a').each(function(){
    $(this).prependTo($(this).parent());
});
```

Alternatively, you could also use this if you only want it to be inserted before its previous sibling.

[**Example Here**](http://jsfiddle.net/67uTN/)

```
$('table td a').each(function(){
    $(this).insertBefore($(this).prev());
});
```

Answer (score 1):

A non-jQuery alternative:

```
[].slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('td')).forEach(function(td) {
    td.insertBefore(td.children[1], td.children[0]);
});
```